# puppet staging::deploy is not working on windows and saying unzip command not found

Tags: windows, puppet

I am using staging::deploy in my puppet script to download and extract the file as below. And I am trying this on windows.

```
staging::deploy{ "jdk1.7.0_04.zip":
      source  => 'http://sometlocation/jdk1.7.0_04.zip', 
      target  => 'E:/PuppetTestData',
}
```

File download is happening but when staging::extract is executed, I am getting below error.

```
Error: Could not find command 'unzip'
```

I have installed unzip.exe on my windows local but still I am getting the same error.

Could anyone suggest me the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `unzip.exe` file is added to PATH on your Windows.
`staging::deploy` makes use of facter fact `path` :

```
Exec{
  path        => $::path,
  ...
}
```

to setup search path used for command execution. Here you find more about [path](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-path) parameter in `exec` resource.

Comment: @Anony If this answer was correct, please mark it as the correct answer (checkbox to the left of the answer)